# Centre of mass of "similar" shapes

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

We have a circular lamina and a circular wire, of the same radius. The centre of mass in both bodies is the centre of the circle, right? So far, no argument can go against this.

*However*, when we repeat the same process with a triangular lamina and a triangular wire frame, this breaks up and the centre of mass isn't the same point anymore. I want to imagine the frame as a lamina of an infinitely thin frame and vaccum in between.. this is supposed to be analogous to a uniform lamina.. My question is, why doesn't this hold? Let's imagine that I have a triangular lamina of metal and I kept cutting similar triangles from it, **such that each similar triangle has its centre of mass coincident on the original triangle**. I will eventually have a metal wire, right? The triangles, being similar and having their centre of masses coincident on each other, shouldn't have any effect on the position of the centre of mass, should it? Okay I know I'm wrong, I have verified this by calculation and drawing, but can anybody give me a satisfying mathematical or physical proof why I'm wrong? I feel the wrong part has to do with them being similar and having the c.m. coincident.. Something doesn't click here yet I can't put my hand on it. Thank you.

Comment: A triangular wire and lamina of the same dimensions will have the same center of mass, I'm not sure how you deduced otherwise. The only way it could be different is if the density is not uniform in the same way...I'm assuming uniform density right now

Comment: In fact your logic that they should be the same by method of growing similar triangles is the essence of the proof of this fact, so your original intuition that they are not the same must be wrong

Comment: @Triatticus No, I had a problem in which there were three uniform wires of 13,5 and 12 cm of length. They form a right angle triangle(obviously), and i had to find the distance of the centre of mass from the 12cm wire. It was 3/2 cm away. The model answer treated it as a compound shape of three wires, not like a lamina in which the centre of mass is at the point of intersection of the medians. I tried the same dimensions in a lamina and the centre of mass turned out to be 5/3 cm from the 12cm side.

Comment: @Triatticus it's not my intuition that tells me I'm wrong, like i just mentioned I tried the calculations both ways and each of them gives a different answer..

Comment: How did you calculate the COM for the lamina?

Comment: Actually the best way to think about it is mass distribution, remember that the center of mass is a mass weighted average, so it wholly depends on the masses of the wire edges also. In your analogy of similar triangles you basically keep that mass ratio the same, however in an arbitrary triangle that itself even though similar in dimensions to a lamina may have a different mass distribution

Comment: Your triangle removal procedure will converge to a wire triangle of *non-uniform* thicknesses. The thickness of each edge will be proportional to the length of the corresponding altitude of the triangle.

Comment: One reason the centers of mass of the disc and circle coincide is the symmetry of the figure. If your triangle were equilateral, the centers of mass of the wire frame and lamina would also coincide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've thought about the anology of cutting out ever larger triangles, and why it doesn't hold.

Consider the image below of a $3,4,5$ triangle with its medians shown. The intersection of the medians is the centre of mass of your lamina triangle.

Inside that are a blue and red triangle.

(*For those affected by colour blindness, the red triangle is the one slightly further to the left.*)

- The blue triangle has its vertices $3/4$ of the way from the centroid
  to each vertex. This represents the cut-outs of triangles with
  centre of mass the same as the larger triangle.
- The red triangle has its sides a perpendicular distance of $1/4$ from
  the edges of the $3,4,5$ triangle. This represents cut-outs
  approaching a wire frame.

It's clear these are not the same, and hence the lamina triangle and wire frame triangle will have different centres of mass.

[image]

Comment: I'm not totally sure where the centre of mass of the wire frame triangle is located. By my analogy, it should be at the incentre - i.e. an equal distance from each side. Is this correct?

Comment: The center of mass of a wire frame need not be equidistant from the edges, if one side is more massive the COM will be closer to that side

Comment: This diagram is just what the question needed. It would be especially clear with a long and skinny needle-shaped triangle.

Comment: "I'm not totally sure where the centre of mass of the wire frame triangle is located." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spieker_center

Comment: That's a really nice answer, thanks. When I said I verified the falseness by drawing I meant something similar but it wasn't as coincise and it was drawn by hand, so I was worried the teeny difference was due to the inaccuracy of my hands. Thanks again.

Comment: What program did you use to draw this?

Comment: The diagram was drawn using GeoGebra online then saved as a PNG file.